# Django template hyperlink don't showing up

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a hyperlink in my template. Here it is how:

```
<a {% url 'favourited' tweet.id%}>{{tweet.favourite.count }}</a>
```

Howerver, it renders only `{{tweet.favourite.count }}`part.

Intrestingly, without hyperlink this `{% url 'favourited' tweet.id%}` returns correct link: `favourited/1`

So where is the problem?

Comment: Nope, the same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you meaning to do:

```
<a href="{% url 'favourited' tweet.id%}">{{tweet.favourite.count}} </a>
```